# How to store all checkboxes from the form when submitting?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of checkboxes representing the profiles I want to save in db.

**HML:**

```
    <tr *ngFor="let profile of profiles | async">
     <input type='checkbox' name="profiles" value='{{profile.id}}' ng-model='profile.checked'> {{profile.name}}
     <td>
       {{profile.id}}
   </td>
```

Then in the typescript I want to iterate the list os profiles and call the create profile service for the ones checked. The service receives a single profile so i want to itare and check if the check box is checked and then I can call the Spring boot service.

How can I do that?

TYPESCRIPT.TS

```
    //Please suggest the code

//The service
this.profileService.createProfile(profile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add Id to input checkboxes something like this

```
id="profile{{profile.id}}"

profileData:any=[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProfiles();
    }

 getProfiles() {
    this.profileService.getPerfisList()
      .subscribe(res=> {
        if (res) {
          this.profilesservice= res;
          this.profileData = this.profilesservice;
         }
      })
  }

 submit() 
  {

    for(var i= 0;i < this.profileData.length ; i++){  
    var id = "profiles" + this.profileData[i].id;
    var resval = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).checked;   
    if(resval)
    {
    this.profileService.createProfile(profile)
     }
    else
     {

      }
  }
```

This will solve your issues.

Comment: Profiles is already declared this this:
profiles: Observable<Profile[]>;

And initiated this way:
this.profiles= this.profileService.getProfilesList();

So I can show then in the form.

The way you suggested is giving me the error:
error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Observable<Perfil[]>'.

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let profile of profiles | async"> whatever profiles data your getting assign to a new variable and use in submit method for loop. then it might work

Comment: Sorry, didnt' understand.
The code is already this way:


<tr *ngFor="let profile of profiles | async">

Comment: I mean your having data in profiles variable right. assign the same data to another variable in .ts file and then use that variable in submit method for loop

Comment: I tryind this:

HTML:
<tr *ngFor="let profile of profilesservice| async">

TS:
profilesservice: Observable<Profile[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.perfisservico = this.perfilService.getPerfisList();
  }

And the code you suggested:
    for(var i= 0;i < this.profiles.length ; i++){  
    var id = "profile" + this.profiles[i].id;
    var resval = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).value;  

And it's giving me the error:
src/app/create-usuario/create-usuario.component.ts:38:30 - error TS2339: Property 'profiles' does not exist on type 'CreateUsuarioComponent'.

Comment: replace this.profiles with this.perfisservico in forloop

Comment: Still giving the error: 
error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Observable<Profile[]>'.

Answer (score 0):

I will paste the entire code here to avoid confusion:

**HTML:**

```
<h3>Criar user</h3>
<div [hidden]="submitted" style="width: 400px;">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">phone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" required [(ngModel)]="user.phone" name="phone">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" required [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email">
        </div>

        <h4>Perfis</h4>
        <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <td>Habilitar/Desabilitar</td>
             <td>ID</td></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let profile of profileservice | async">
             <input type='checkbox' name="profile" value='{{profile.id}}' id="profile{{profile.id}}" ng-model='profile.checked'> {{profile.name}}
             <td>
               {{profile.id}}
           </td>
           <td>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>

<div [hidden]="!submitted">
    <h4>You submitted successfully!</h4>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { UserService } from './../user.service';
import { User } from './../user';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from './../profile.service';
import { Profile } from "./../profile";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { UserProfileService } from './../userprofile.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-user',
  templateUrl: './create-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-user.component.css']
})
export class CreateUserComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User = new User();
  submitted = false;
  profilesservice: Observable<Profile[]>;
  response: any;
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private profileService: ProfileService, private userprofileService: UserProfileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profilesservice = this.profileService.getPerfisList();
  }

  newUser(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.user = new User();
  }

save() {
    this.userService.createUser(this.user)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.response = res;
        console.log(res);
        this.user = new User();
    for(var i= 0;i < this.profilesservice.length ; i++){  
    var id = "profiles" + this.profilesservice[i].id;
    var resval = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).value;   
    if(resval)
    {
    //Here i want to call this.userprofileService.createUserProfile(profile)
     }
    else
     {
      alert(2);
      }
    }




  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.save();
  }




}
```

Comment: It's not reaching the piece of code to call the profileservice.

Tryied this:
```
    if(resval)
    {
    //this.perfilService.createPerfil(this.perfilData[i]);
    alert("1");
     }
    else
     {
alert("2");
      }}
```

Not working with checked or non checked from screen.

Comment: It has this:

Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project: ƒ}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: FilterOperator}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object

Comment: Trying to log console.log(this.perfilData[0]); or console.log(this.perfilData.length); it's giving "undefined"

Comment: What does this method do getPerfisList()?

Comment: updated my answer please check it. this should work

Comment: Now the profiles and checkboxes are not loading in the screen.

Comment: Use profileData in ngFor. If still doesn’t show debug the getprofiles method in .ts file

Comment: Idk how to debug ts, but I tried this:
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProfiles();
    }

 getProfiles() {
    this.profileService.getPerfisList()
      .subscribe(res=> {
        if (res) {
          this.profilesservice= res;
console.log(profilesservice);
          this.profileData = this.profilesservice;
console.log(profileData );
         }
      })
  }

And it's not printing anything.
I think it's not reaching it properly.

When changed async pipe to profileData it pops the error "CreateUsuarioComponent.html:14 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Comment: remove async pipe and try one more time.

Comment: Ok, now it's loadin the profiles and reaching all the code , thanks.

But this
    if(resval)
    {
Should be a check if the checkbox is checked, this way is always returning true.
How can i check if the checkbox is checked andonly then call the service?

Comment: you can upvote and accept my answer.  if(resval) { } will check the checkbox if it is true or not. if it is true it gets inside to if condition then you can call the service

Comment: My html is this way: 
value='{{profile.id}}'

So this is what resval is printing while looping:
8
9
10
11
This are the id from the table not if they're checked.

How should I do the html so the value is if it's checke or not?

Comment: Tried to remove this value tag but then all the checkboxes are reaching the code as true, even the ones not checked.

Comment: This is my current thml:
 <input type='checkbox' id="perfil{{perfil.id}}">

Comment: var id = "perfil" + this.profileData[i].id;
    var resval = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).value;

Comment: This did the magic:
var resval = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).checked;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203050/discussion-between-raj-and-dm-am).

Comment: Thank you for the upvote and I didn't see .checked. Thank you for correcting me

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to edit the profile? If so you need to change `ng-model='profile.checked'` to `[(ng-model)]='profile.checked'`. The syntax you have used won't create a binding